# Hangfire Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, hangfire

In my project I have a problem with background Job. I am using Hangfire and default .Net Core Dependency injection.

Startup.cs

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizable, AuthorizeService>();
services.AddTransient<IEditable, ConfigureService>();
services.AddTransient<IRequested, RequestService>();
services.AddTransient<INotified, NotificationService>();
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage("ConnectionString"));
```

Configure:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

When my Job tries to run, I receive this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Mapper.Services.RequestService' has been registered.

What am I do wrong?

Comment: DI knows how to deal with IRequested by providing a RequestService. But that is for classes asking for IRequested. It does not know how to deal with classes asking for RequestService directly. so you need to add RequestService to services as well.

Comment: when you run your job , in your contructor of the job class are you using `IRequested` or `RequestService` , you should use `IRequested` so it will understand the `RequestedService` will be used/registered to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DI knows how to deal with `IRequested` by providing a `RequestService`. But that is for classes asking for `IRequested`. It does not know how to deal with classes asking for `RequestService` directly.

So based on the error message you need to register `RequestService` with services as well.

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizable, AuthorizeService>();
services.AddTransient<IEditable, ConfigureService>();
services.AddTransient<IRequested, RequestService>();
services.AddTransient<RequestService, RequestService>(); //<-- 
services.AddTransient<INotified, NotificationService>();
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage("ConnectionString"));
```

---

Update based on comment.

You should also consider updating the Job to be dependent on the `IRequested` abstraction as apposed to the implemented `RequestService` if that is indeed the case.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514099/hangfire-server-unable-to-pick-job-in-case-of-strategy-design-pattern